# What does the combination of '#${parentId}' mean in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Here's the line:

```
const parent = document.querySelector(`#${parentId}`);
```

I know what the `const parent`, `document.querySelector()` and `parentId` mean and do.

I'm struggling to find out what the `#`, `$` and `{}` do as a combination.

Here's the full `.js`:

```
(function(document) {
  const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('[data-next]');

  for (const item of buttons) {

    const parentId = item.getAttribute('data-parent');

    const parent = document.querySelector(`#${parentId}`);
    console.log(parent);
    const nextDivId = item.getAttribute('data-next');
    const nextDiv = document.querySelector(`#${nextDivId}`);
    if (!nextDiv) {
      console.error('could not find next div for button ', item);
    }
    item.addEventListener('click', function() {
      nextDiv.classList.toggle('hidden');
      parent.classList.toggle('hidden');
    });
  }
})(document);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is called Template Literals. From the documentation:

> Template literals are string literals allowing embedded expressions. You can use multi-line strings and string interpolation features with them. They were called "template strings" in prior editions of the ES2015 specification.

Technically the code creates a string for `document.querySelector()` which will at the end of the day a selector for the parent's id.

Example code:

```js
const parentId = 'randomid';
const result = `#${parentId}`;

console.log(result);
```

So you can think about that code as the following:

```
const parentId = item.getAttribute('data-parent');
const selector = `#${parentId}`;

const parent = document.querySelector(selector);
```

Read further here: [Template Literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

I hope this helps!

Comment: So it basically is just making it a string with #$?

Comment: So once you have a variable called `value` like `const value = 'text'` then the template literal will evaluate the `${value}` as a string resulting `text`. If you add `#${value}` then the result will be `#text`. I hope this clarifies your question.

Answer (score 1):

`${parentId}` is a template literal expression

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Here it is saying, "get the variable `parentId` and prepend a hashtag, to indicate an id for the `querySelector()` function."

In the below code for example, the line renders as:

```
const parent = document.querySelector("#a")
```

```js
const parentId = "a"
const parent = document.querySelector(`#${parentId}`)
parent.style.color = "#f00"
```

```html
<div id="a">Text</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's called a template literal.

You can think about it as putting some parsed code into a string.

So, if you want to put a variable into the string '#', you can do like this:

```js
const someId = 'someid';

const idWithHashTag = `#${someId}`;
```

You have to use the backticks (`), and then you can use`${}` and do something inside the curly braces.